# Machinekey Validationkey in webconfig

Tags: asp.net

If someone know the machineKey and validationKey of my hosted website, does the security compromise or someone can access my website or can make any changing? Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will get your website machine key

[Click here](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey)

You can setting up your machine key

[Click here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-machine-key)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  If somebody knows your *machineKey* and *validationKey* settings, you must assume that your site can be compromised.  Change your keys to new random values if you think they are no longer secret.